# How do I enter the git config command for Git Bash?

Tags: git, bash

I tried to enter git config -- global user name and I keep getting error messages when trying to configure my Git Bash account. I am using windows 7 and I have downloaded Git Version 1.9.5

Comment: What are the error messages telling you? Post it here.

Comment: What command are you trying to run and what is the error message? Please read and understand this: [ask]

Comment: Downvoted, will upvote back when you give information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you were trying to globally set your username. This is the correct command:

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
```

Have a look at [Pro Git Book: 1.6 Getting Started - First-Time Git Setup](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) for a nice summary.